# PHP and Ajax: Impossible to execute LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE (mysql) from Ajax call

Tags: php, mysql, permissions, load-data-infile

My code processes a .txt file that contains approximately 50,000 clients, which I must enter into a table using the MySQL batching mechanism "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE" (Bulk Insert in the Sql Server's world or MongoDb)

My code works fine if I do it from the same browser, but if I do the same with an Ajax call, it returns me "false", so I imagine that an apache or PHP security reason blocks me from executing this procedure. Does anyone know what I should do?

My code is:

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

$mysqli = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'user_name', 'secret', 'prueba');

$file = $_POST["file"];

if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Errno: " . $mysqli->connect_errno . "\n";
    echo "Error: " . $mysqli->connect_error . "\n";
    exit;
}

$sql = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/var/www/node/importacion/api/csv_files/{$file}' INTO TABLE cuentas FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'";

try {
    $resp = $mysqli->query($sql);
    $mysqli->close();
    $respuesta = array(
        "server" => $resp
    );
}catch (Exception $e){
    print_r($e->getMessage());
}


echo json_encode($respuesta);
```

Comment: Have you checked "/var/www/node/importacion/api/csv_files/{$file}" is in the group of mysql and www-data?

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: What is the Ajax call? You have 3 print statements. 2 Are error codes and 2 end up with JSON. Need to see your AJAX call to see how you are handling calls and return

Comment: My ajax call is: 
`$.ajax({
    data  : "file="+archivo,
    type  : "post",
    dataType: "json",
    url  : "http://localhost/procesarBulk.php",
    success : function(data){
     if(data.server==false){
      alert("Hemos tenido problemas para procesar el lote");
     }else{
      alert("Bien, finalizamos todo");
     }
    }
   });`

Answer (score 1):

**Not an answer yet**, but debugging. `AJAX` is expecting a `JSON` string, and with errors, you are providing simple TEXT which might screw things up and you're missing the error messages.

Update your php:

```
$respuesta = '';
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
     $respuesta .= "Errno: " . $mysqli->connect_errno . "\n";
     $respuesta .= "Error: " . $mysqli->connect_error . "\n";
    // exit;
}

...
catch (Exception $e){
    $respuesta .= 'Exception Error: '.print_r($e->getMessage(),1);
}
```

Update your AJAX:

```
$.ajax(
{ 
  data : "file="+archivo,
  type : "post", 
  dataType: "json", 
  url : "http://localhost/procesarBulk.php", 
  success : function(data){ 
    if(data.server==false){ 
        alert("Hemos tenido problemas para procesar el lote : "+
           JSON.stringify(data)
        ); 
    }else{ 
       alert("Bien, finalizamos todo"); 
    } 
  },
  error: function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert(JSON.stringify({
        title: "Connection Error",
        typeAnimated: true,
        content: "There was a connection problem with "+this.url+'=> ('+textStatus+'):'+errorThrown+". Please try again"                
  }));

});
```

See what extra info you get.

**ALSO** check your web server log for errors

Comment: Thanks for your reply, my friend, I found the reason for my error. The problem is that the file when I want to read it still does not finish being created, for that reason it can not continue the process. I solved it by placing a sleep(5), although it is a temporary solution, I could see that that is the reason. Thank you very much.